# which version of swift does Apple's library reference use?

Tags: xcode, swift

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:

```
Declaration
SWIFT
func beginTrackingWithTouch(_ touch: UITouch,
                  withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

with an `?` at the end of UIEvent.

However I can do `override public func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent) -> Bool`

But not `override public func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool`
(notice that ? is at the end of UIEvent)

I'm using swift 1.2

So Does apple doc show 2.0 syntax? if so, is there a way to change the version of the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://developer.apple.com/library/ there are links to both

- the "Current Release" which at present is the iOS 8 SDK that comes with Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2
- the "Pre-Release" which at present is the iOS 9 SDK that comes with Xcode 7 GM and Swift 2.

If you open the [UIControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779) from the "Current Release" then
you will find

```
func beginTrackingWithTouch(_ touch: UITouch,
                  withEvent event: UIEvent) -> Bool
```

which works in Xcode 6.4 with Swift 1.2.

(In this particular case you can simply remove the "prerelease" part of
your URL to jump to the current release documentation. I don't know
if that works in general.)

Comment: Thanks! I would search in google and see the doc, so in this case I'd have to try removing the "prerelease" from the url. I don't see a better way of finding doc from your explanation though. I tried setting different deployment target (from 9.0 to 8.0) in the doc (settings). but no avail.